# How to preserve a Timer instance

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, back-button

I have a view controller (TimerVC) in which I run a timer and I am showing the current state of the timer in a label.

My timer function:

```
func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

After user taps "Back" button on the navigation bar when TimerVC is open (step 1), when the user taps a button to show TimerVC again (step 2), I can see in the console that timer is still running in the background but its state is not being updated in the label.

I guess that this is because TimerVC's current instance is destroyed when user press "Back" button, and when the user opens TimerVC again, it creates a new instance of TimerVC, thus the label cannot be updated.

I have no idea how I can preserve my TimerVC instance when the user taps on the back button in Navigation Bar and restore that old TimerVC instance when the user triggers a segue to TimerVC.

To solve this problem at step 2, I tried to go back in the navigation stack instead of creating a new push segue to the TimerVC, but it did not work, probably because old TimerVC view controller could not be found in the stack, so it could not be restored. This is not surprising, it should have probably been destroyed when the back button was tapped.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view controller which is before the TimerVC have a property

```
 var timerVC = TimerVC()
```

when you need to show it just push it

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(self.timerVC, animated:true)
```

This way you will always be dealing with the same instance of `TimerVC`

Comment: This works but if user taps back button again in the view controller which is before the TimerVC, the property is destroyed, so I cannot access to the same TimerVC instance again. What is the best practice to solve this? Should I create a property in AppDelegate when app is launched and refer it in other view controllers?

Comment: @Teo Creating a singleton class and running the timer in that singleton class is the best practice. If you want to persist the counter value and resume timer even after killing and re-launching the app, use userdefaults in the singleton class

Comment: Then I think it would be better to have a single model object which would encapsulate the timer. It will then be ok to create a new TimerVC every time you need it because every new instance of TimerVC will deal with the same model object. You can (and most likely should) make the model object a singletone

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is Timer.scheduledTimer will create a singleton instance, which will not be killed, even if you vc is de-initialized.

What you might want to do is create the timer in a different class, like a `TimerManager` or something.

This class will maintain the state of the timer, and other such informations.

Now when you open your TimerVC, you will check whether there is timer running, from your TimerManager class.

Remember to keep this `TimerManager` `singleton`. So the instance of `TimerManager`  is not de-initialized.

If the timer is running, you get the timer values, etc , from that TimerManager class, else you create a new timer in that TimerManager class.

This will also help you to invalidate the timer, when your job is done. And if you have different flows and lots of push/pops of view controllers, and then you come back to your TimerVC, you can still access this value.